# Which surface to use in Ampere's law?

Tags: magnetostatics

In calculating the current enclosed by an Amperian loop, one must, in general evaluate an integral of the form

$$I_\text{encl} = \int \mathbf{J}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{a}$$

The trouble is, there are infinitely many surfaces that share the same boundary line. Which one are we supposed to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The identity is correct for *all* of the infinitely many surfaces (isn't math amazing?).

In general you either have a surface you care about in the first place or are in a position to *choose* the easiest surface.