# Displacement current derivation

Tags: maxwell-equations, calculus

A common explanation for the reason why displacement current is needed is in the following diagram (Giancoli):

[image]

I can appreciate the reason why we need displacement current, however I really don't get the reasoning they used. The closed loop integral can have a "membrane" to catch the current and can be stretched over the capacitor and then the integral would give 0 if it wasn't for the displacement current.

I am quite confused as to why it is valid to stretch the membrane and still expect the same result. Unfortunately, I have only done single variable calculus, but I still would really like to know why it is valid that this membrane can be stretched.

Comment: [Related?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/317660/104696)

Comment: Short answer: It's valid to stretch the membrane, because [Ampere's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law) applies to any shape of surface we choose.